# How do I indicate that certain features (words) and certain documents are more important than others in Naive Bayes?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am developing a binary document classifier using sklearn. I want to indicate that certain features (words) are more (or less) important and certain documents are more (or less) important for learning.

Comment: It would be great if you show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) you can get the number of occurrences (frequency) of each word in the text corpus:

```
vec = CountVectorizer().fit(corpus)
bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in     vec.vocabulary_.items()]
words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

You can also get importance of each feature (word) based on univariate statistical test, using [SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
...
skb = SelectKBest(chi2, k="all").fit(X, y)

feature_importnace = skb.scores_
```

By training a RandomForestClassifier:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

model = clf.fit(X, y)

# Calculate feature importances
importances = model.feature_importances_
```